# Trouble reading string text into an array and counting letters

Tags: arrays, string

I am tasked to write a letter histogram which should be able to read any text and count the letters and output them in a neat way.

My question for this code so far is how to read the text into an array, I am stuck. I use two functions for this, one to read the text string into an array, and another function to output the array in this manner:
A: x
B: x
C: x
n: x

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <cmath>
 using namespace std;

const int ANTAL_BOKSTAVER = 26;
void berakna_histogram_abs ();
void skriv_histogram_abs (int bokstav, int antal);


int main()
{
  int i;
  char alfabet;
  string text;
  cout << "Skriv in texten: ";
  getline (cin, text);

  void berakna_histogram_abs();
  void skriv_histogram_abs();
  return 0;
}

void berakna_histogram_abs ()
{
string text;
char str[100]= {getline};

int i= 0, alfabet[26]={0}, j;

while (str[i]!='\0')
    {
      if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i]<='z')
      {
          j = str[i] - 'a';
          ++alfabet[j];
      }
      i++;
    }
}

void skriv_histogram_abs()
{
 int alfabet[26]={0};
    int i;
    cout << "Frekvensen av alla bokstäver är: " <<endl;
  for (i=0; i < 26; i++)
    cout << char(i + 'a')<<" : " << alfabet[i] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One can create and pass an array as below.

- Create the array once.
- Pass it as parameter. The variable and parameter names may differ.
  So I renamed the text variable as demonstration.

For a histogram one needs to scale the length.

```
int main()
{
  int i;
  string in_text;
  cout << "Skriv in texten: ";
  getline (cin, in_text);

  int alfabet[26] = {0};
  berakna_histogram_abs(in_text, alfabet);
  skriv_histogram_abs(alfabet);
  return 0;
}

void berakna_histogram_abs (string text, int* alfabet)
{
}

void skriv_histogram_abs(int* alfabet)
{
  int maxfreq = 0;
  int i;
  for (i=0; i < 26; i++)
    if (alfabet[i] > maxfreq)
      maxfreq = alfabet[i];

  double ratio = 60.0 / (maxfreq == 0 ? 1 : maxfreq);

  cout << "Frekvensen av alla bokstäver är: " <<endl;
  for (i=0; i < 26; i++)
  {
    cout << char(i + 'a')<<" : ";
    int laengd = (int)(alfabet[i] * ratio);
    for (int j = 0; j < laengd; ++j)
      cout << '■';
    cout << " " << alfabet[i] << endl;
  }
}
```

Arrays are generally passed as pointers.

I scaled the bar to some 60 characters, so the line length is kept below 80.